# How can i use env in Dockerfile while gitlab build?

Tags: gitlab, dockerfile, cicd

this is my build.yml

```
.build_vue_template: &build-client
...
  script:
...
    - echo "$ENV_CLIENT" > ./client/.env
```

```
build:client_develop:
...
  variables:
    ENV_CLIENT: "$ENV_CLIENT_DEVELOP"
```

this is my Dockerfile

```
COPY client .
```

i try to build my client and want to use env in Dockerfile

how can i use env in my Dockerfile? thanks

Answer (score 0):

COPY command in Dockerfile will not copy hidden files starting with dot(.)

Use below given Dockerfile to use the .env inside docker image

```
COPY client .
COPY client/.env ./.env
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for using environment variable in dockerfile

```
FROM busybox
ENV my_variable=some_value
WORKDIR /app
```